# Xulrunner Eclipse Luna 64bit Windows crashes

Tags: swt, xulrunner, eclipse-luna

I am using the SWT Browser with Mozilla engine. It works find inside Kepler 64Bit Windows 7 64Bit.
I started to move to Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 64bit and Xulrunner 24.x. I am not able to get it running. It crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:258)
```

I do not know which SWT version Luna 4.4.1 is using - There were people, that said, that SWT 4.4 is working with xulrunner 24.x

I also have installed the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables 2010. 
Is there anybody, that could help me with that tricky problem?
Thanking you very much in advance.

kind regards 
Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very important to take a 64bit version of XulRunner for Windows. this can be found here:
http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Download

Comment: That link now returns a 403 response